# How to play live video from RTMP url?

Tags: ios, swift, rtmp, video-player

I am using VLC media player by MobileVLCKit.When i add VLC in my project app size increased. So i want to change library for video player. Can you suggest any library for RTMP url?

Only playing live video from url. Not streaming from customer side. Can you tell me video player library. its support RTMP url. or How to play the video from RTMP url?

Comment: See Help Center to find out what types of questions are acceptable.

Comment: This question about Video player in swift language.